# Working over a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm a bit of a beginner to Haskell so I'm struggling a little with the strict type stuff, just wondering if someone can help me with a function I'm trying to build. Basically, it takes a list of lists, for example:

```
[[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [0,3,4]]
```

and adds them together into one list translating the later lists by the number of positions along it is. So working on the example list it would actually be doing something like:

```
foldl (zipWith +) [] [[1,2,3],[0,7,6,8],[0,0,0,3,4]]
```

Here's my current function (which gets type errors):

```
    addLists :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
    addLists [[]] = []
    addLists [[x]] = [x]
    addLists [x:xs] = zipWith (+) [x] ([0]++ (addLists xs))
```

Comment: Please state explicitly what you want the result of `addLists [[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [0,3,4]]` to be. It is not obvious from your question.

Comment: It appears that you've edited your question to clarify it, but I'm afraid I still don't understand. What should the result of `addLists [[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [0,3,4]]` look like? The example you gave, `foldl (zipWith +) [] [[1,2,3],[0,7,6,8],[0,0,0,3,4]]` doesn't type-check, and I can't figure out what you intended it to do.

Comment: Do you want the result to be `[1, 2+7, 3+6+0, 8+4, 4]` = `[1,9,9,12,4]`?

Comment: Sorry, the output should be `[1, 2+7, 3+6+0, 8+3, 4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want

```
import Data.List (transpose)

addLists :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
addLists xs = map sum . transpose $ zipWith (\n x -> replicate n 0 ++ x) [0..] xs
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain exactly how it works? I can pretty much follow, but not quite!

Comment: @npfedwards Sorry, I meant to come back and expand this answer, but somethign else came up. Will get to it soon, I hope!

Comment: A bit nicer: `addLists = map sum . transpose . zipWith (++) (inits (repeat 0))`. The interesting part is `transpose`, which is a `Data.List` function worth being familiar with with. Since this is a composition, you can play with each part individually to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 6):

Note that `([0]++)` is the same as `(0:)`, which will make it look tidier and save us a nanosecond or two.
(I'm joking with the nanosecond thing - no human can tell when something's a nanosecond faster, but it is nicer this way anyway.)

Let's first think about making the lists you need. We want

```
postponeLists [[1,2,3], [7,6,8], [10,20,30,40]] 
             = [[1,2,3], [0,7,6,8], [0,0,10,20,30,40]]
             = [1,2,3] : ones that should have zero in front of them
```

That's enough information for a definition:

```
postponeLists [] = []
postponeLists (l:ls) = l : map (0:) (postponeLists ls)
```

Now you said

```
foldl (zipWith +) [] [[1,2,3],[0,7,6,8],[0,0,0,3,4]]
```

but you mean

```
foldl (zipWith (+)) [] [[1,2,3],[0,7,6,8],[0,0,0,3,4]]
```

but unfortunately, that gives you `[]` because `zipWith` stops as soon as any of the lists run out of elements.
We need some way of zipping them that doesn't stop.

Solution 1: find the longest one, make them all that `maxlength` using `take maxlength.(++ repeat 0)`
Solution 2: write another zipWith function that doesn't stop.

I prefer solution 2. Let's look at the [definition of `zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#zipWith)

```
zipWith :: (a->b->c) -> [a]->[b]->[c]
zipWith f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWith f as bs
zipWith _ _      _      = [] -- here's the problem - it stops as soon as any list is empty
```

OK, let's not stop then:

```
zipWithMore :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipWithMore f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWithMore f as bs
zipWithMore f []      bs      = bs -- if there's more in bs, use that
zipWithMore f as      []      = as -- if there's more in as, use that
```

Now you can replace `zipWith (+)` with `zipWithMore (+)`. I'll leave the punchline to you.

Comment: `(0:)` won't save you any nanoseconds over `([0]++)`, at least not with `ghc -O2`. `(:)` sometimes *is* nicer than `(++)` where either is applicable, but you shouldn't let nanosecond speculation like that shape your code.

Comment: @shachaf Of course not! I was pointing out by jokingly saying "save a nanosecond or two" that it's unnecessary. `(0:)` is nicer though, and I wanted to introduce that habit. Who cares about nanoseconds with a problem like this? I've made it clearer it wasn't meant seriously.